# Inline Bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, filecontents

I know how to use a .bib file to add BibTex and use that in the main document. Is there a way I can include the bib-file in my latex document and not use an external bib-file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think we have to clear up the terminology here. If you refer to bibtex, you refer to the executable, e.g. bibtex.exe on a windows system.
The bib-file on the other hand is your database of entries.

If you want to create a bibliography without using the bibtex executable, you can use the classic

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{key} John Doe {\em Title and stuff}  2013.

\end{thebibliography}
```

in your document which you can cite with `\cite{key}` in the text.

If your question is if you can use a bib-file without bibtex. The answer is - no.
Technically the answer is yes because you could use the biber executable with the bibaltex package but because biber and bibtex are kind of the same I still say no.

If your question is if you can include the content of your bib file in you main document the answer is - yes.

Use the filecontents environment and paste the content of your bib file in it. LaTeX will then automatically generate a bib file during the compilation. That way you can send a single tex file to a friend and he can compile the document including the bibliography. You still have to use bibtex though.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}

@article{key,
author={},
title={}
.
.
.
}

\end{filecontents}
```

Comment: The filecontents is what I am looking for. Also, please edit my question to improve clarity.

Comment: Good, glad I can help. Because the filecontents+bibtex stuff has been asked before, I flagged your question as a possible duplicate.

Comment: It should be said that the filecontents package has to be loaded to define the filecontents environment.